How do I recover my Ubuntu 20.04 system if I uninstalled python3 and the desktop itself?

So I was loging in to my ubuntu system but suddenly I was stuck in this terminal shell.
I tried using sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop && ubuntu-gnome-desktop but it's removed because it came with python.
All of them have unmet dependencies and broken packages.
Does anyone know how to do this, I'm banging my head with this one!!!

If you know what commands were used to destroy your system, please say so in your question. We can help you best if we don't need to guess what might have happened. Help us to help you.

You should still be able to use a text terminal, however GUI relies on python3 and it needs to be the specific version of python3 the system came with IF you want everything to work & be trusthworthy (ie. if you change default version the best result is features stop working; the worst thing is data corruption as they're working incorrectly!).  If you get python3-minimal installed & default you should be able to use user-tools such as apt etc to fix the rest. Until then, simple wget and dpkg usually work to get a partially functional system, but use your system at text terminal.

The easiest fix (fastest too) is to just non-destructively re-install a Desktop system in my opinion.  Otherwise reversing the change(s) you made will be next, and you provided only vague clues without specifics as to what package change(s) you made.  If your sources have been heavily modified you can also experience other issues; so restoring sources to default can often be useful.

Use another computer to flash Ubuntu (say, 24.04) on a live USB.
Boot the live USB in your computer, and browse your file system to backup any necessary data from your home folder.
Now use it to reinstall ubuntu.

I only have Ubuntu(18.04) on a live DVD not a USB

18.04 has reached end of support. Please use a USB drive to flash 24.04 (supported until 2029 - till then, you will not have to upgrade)

Ok but since I wanted to keep all my applications, documents, files etc. I don't have a usb but I have an empty DVD

You can copy all your files and reinstall all the applications. Ubuntu 24.04 will not fit on a DVD. If you don't have one, you can borrow a USB drive from a friend for the installation

Let's assume you have completely removed all python3 packages and dependencies. Apt needs python3, so apt doesn't work anymore.

Use a different system to locate the 20.04 URLs for the following packages:

python3-minimal
python3.8-minimal
python3
python3.8
libpython3.8-stdlib


Use wget to download each package.

Use dpkg to install each downloaded package.


Apt should now work again.

I only downloaded just python3 which is the right version, what do you mean locate the 20.04 URLs

Different releases of Ubuntu (20.04 vs 24.04) use different packages. If you mistakenly install the python3 package for the wrong release, you will make your problem much  worse.

Ok but how do I locate the 20.04 URLs using what system?

If you don't already have the skills to locate packages and use dpkg using a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, then it's much easier and faster to simply back up your data and then reinstall Ubuntu. That will also cure any other undisclosed damage caused by your disaster.
